# MariaDB not release heap memory

Tags: mariadb

I am using MariaDB database for my application, but i am facing a problem with it.
It shows me a unique behaviour, when I `select COUNT(*) from table` with 4,00,00,000 rows.

then it increase the size of heap until it fetches the result of COUNT(*), and after finishing the query it does not release the occupied heap memory.

It does not increase again if I execute the same query, but heap memory increases again if I choose different table with 4,00,00,000 rows.

I am not able to understand what is the problem behind that?

Comment: You should submit your edit as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Found:**

There is a tokudb macro 'tokudb_cache_size' which takes approx 50% of memory DEFAULT. 50% is the preferable cache size. so i think its not a problem. :)